# Magento without shopping cart and affiliate tracking

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, affiliate

I intend to use Magento for my web site , except that I wont be selling any products but will be referring to third party retailers from my web site and will be disabling the shopping cart on my web site , I want the users of my site to be treated as affiliates for my web site , the affiliates on my web site will get paid when they make a purchase on the third party site I refer them to.I myself will be a super affiliate who will be enrolled in an affiliate network .

Is it something that could be achieved using Magento?Are there any Magento extensions for this that allow you to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know if there are any existing modules that do this and exactly suit your requirements, but I do know it's possible if you're willing to develop something custom.

Funnily enough I was reading about exactly this in Oleg Ishenko's book: http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-product-types-developers-guide/

The tutorial basically guides you through how to create a custom product type which can set a cookie and links to a third party site (and track the conversions) when you try to place it in your cart. While not complete, it should give you a good starting point. The code of the tutorial is available on Github: https://github.com/varinen/Solvingmagento_AffiliateProduct